# how do i create roles and use those roles in JSPS?

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

how do I create user defined roles and then how do I use them to code my JSPS to present them according to the user role type in a spring MVC web application

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly.

Use jstl.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

With the " if " condition, you can create different menu calls for different users.

[JSTL - Core  Tag](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm)

```
<c:if test="${example != null}">
     <center>
         ${example}
     </center>    
</c:if>
```

Comment: Actually, I wished to know how to create role(s) for each user who is going to use my application later on. Let's say the user chooses certain groups(specific to the application) to be a part of during the sign up process , how I do I then create roles both in the application and the database table columns corresponding to the groups user has chosen. Afterwards , if I wish to present the view of the JSPS which are related to individual groups ,according to the user accessing the page , how do I come to know about the user and their individual details @1100

Comment: you can then create filters. Which will check the login password and give them different rights.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to do that.

1.Create a role entity.

2.Create a user entity.

3.Establish relationship between both tables like (OneToMany or @ManyToMany based on your requirement)

4.Insert a role in table.

5.create a user by assigning the role to the user.

6.Once DB relationships are done then inside JSP page you can get role and put a condition to check that and you are done.

**Code for step 1 :**

```
@Entity
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    private String roleName;

    private String description;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //getters and setters and other fields like roleName,description etc.
}
```

**Step 2 &3:**

```
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;

   //getters and setters and other fields like password,etc.

}
```

Step 6 :

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN" >
write code here which only ADMIN can see
</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: can you provide me link to some tutorial . I just know about the authentication process and don't know authorization . Bdw, Thanks for the help @Alien

Comment: start with this as a beginner http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/

Comment: let them go through it  . Regards @Alien